# How to write convert jpeg to png on python?

Tags: python, image, imagemagick-convert

I need to write script in Python, like [this](https://onlinejpgtools.com/convert-jpg-to-png) with options:

- Enable PNG transparency
- Treat similar colors as transparent. 5%

How can I do this?

### Potential solutions

ffmpeg, imagemagick

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read [ask], and provide a [mre]. What have you tried so far? Why do your solutions not meet your expectations?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you *"want to treat similar colours as transparent 5%"*? Similar to what? What is the 5% for? Please give an example input and corresponding output image and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV

- Read the input
- Define the desired color (blue) to be made transparent
- Define the tolerance amount (5%)
- Create upper and lower bounds on the color according to the tolerance
- Threshold on color and invert
- Put the threshold result into the alpha channel of the input
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg')

# specify blue color
color = (230,160,120)
b = color[0]
g = color[1]
r = color[2]

# specify tolerance as percent
tol = 5
tol = 5/100

# make lower and upper bounds as color minus/plus 5%
bl = int((1-tol) * b)
gl = int((1-tol) * g)
rl = int((1-tol) * r)
lower = (bl,gl,rl)
bu = int((1+tol) * b)
gu = int((1+tol) * g)
ru = int((1+tol) * r)
upper = (bu,gu,ru)

# threshold on color and invert
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
mask = 255 - mask

# put mask into alpha channel
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('barn_transp_blue.png', result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Transparent result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        img = Image.open(images_dir +'/'+ filename)
        img.save(create_path +'/'+ filename.split('.')[0]+'.png', 'png')
```

Comment: The first line opens the image(replace `filename` with your image name and its extension. The second changes the extension and saves file to the same directory

Comment: I need to convert image, not rename this

Comment: The `img.save` does that. It's not mandatory, you do `create_path +'/'+ filename.split('.')[0]+'.png`, you may save your open file to png using an filename you prefer.